# Read Array of Double from JSON file with Delphi and superobject

Tags: json, delphi

I often have json files with arrays of floating point numbers.

{
  ...
  "a":[21.2937602,-2044.79571,250.096163],
  ...
}

I read the above using superobject with this function:

```
function fvec(key: string): TDoubleDynArray;
var
    arr: TSuperArray;
    i, n: Integer;
begin
    arr := obj[key].AsArray;
    n := arr.Length;
    SetLength(Result, n);
    for i := 0 to n-1 do
        Result[i] := arr.D[i]
end;
```

But, I keep thinking that I am missing some obvious way to read an array of double directly.

Something like...

value := obj['a'].AsFVec;

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know if this can be done?

SuperObject does not offer any such functionality. However, it's easy to write your own functions to do so, as you have done.